# Multi-node environment - individual node app server healthcheck

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, nagios, health-monitoring

We have 3 servers, each running an instance of Tomcat, with an Apache webserver also on each server.  A common domain name, ie. megaapp-prod.xxxx.com, is used and a load balancer distributes traffic to each of the appservers, one on each server. Each app container has it's own IP address that we can use in a desktop \etc\hosts file to bypass the load balancer and point to an individual node for testing purposes.

I am looking to do an http based health check on each container directly, however the tool we are using to do the health monitor cannot use a host file approach.  We are having difficulty using the IP of each individual app server in the URL address directly (ie. http://10.1.86.15/appName/, as opposed to using a host file override. "appName" is the name of our java application.  http://megaapp-prod.xxxx.com/appName/ is the standard link to the application.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance - Joe

Comment: What do you mean "cannot use a host file approach" and "host file override"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that each of those Tomcat/Apache hosts also have a unique machine name.  You ought to be able to contact them using those unique names AND the specific port(s) the sites are on.  All of the web page checks I've ever used, supported either machine names or IPs - but you will often have to state a port number to reach the individual 'back-end' servers' listening ports - as they may not be set up to use port 80 (http) or 88 (https).  Tomcats almost never run directly on those ports.  And the Apache process may have been changed to a different port due to load balancing and/or security specs.